# DOM cast to string

Tags: reactjs

I have a DOM that I want to cast to a string, then to parse
How can I do it?
I tried many different libraries, apparently I don’t understand something

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
        <div className="classStyle">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
           <div className="insideStyle">
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
           </div>
        </div>
     )
   }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

in another component i invoke such a construct

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ExampleComponent);
console.info(node);
```

`node` contains my component, but how do I cast this to a string to parse?
I tried to use such constructions

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)
```

but this function `renderToString()` accepts a `ReactElement` as input, and `node` is just `Element`

Comment: Have you tried `node.innerHTML`? Since you already have the dom element you don't need React .

Comment: @Cristian Martinez, this does not work
I need a react, because I'm trying to cast the react component to the string and in `node` there is no `innerHTML` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will work

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ExampleComponent);
console.info((node as Element).innerHTML);
```